# Making li's spread in the entire ul navbar

Tags: html, css

Hey I want to make a navbar with flexbox.

How to make all 3 li's spread across entire ul with even space between li's? Here is my code and its not working :( I tried justify content: space-around and it doesnt work. The li's are still close to each other

```css
/** global element styling **/

@import 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700';

body {
  background-color: #eee;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}

.logo {
 flex-basis:40%;
 border: 1px solid red;
}

.logo img {
 width:100%;
 max-width: 300px;
}

header {
 display: flex;
}

header nav {
 border: 1px solid black;
 width: 60%;
 display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-around;
}

header nav ul {

}

#nav-bar ul li {
 display: inline-flex;
 justify-content: space-between;
 flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
 <title>Product Landing Page</title>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
<div class="page-wrapper">
<!--Header-->
 <header id="header">

<!-- Logo -->  
 <div class="logo">
   <img id="header-img" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/original_trombones.png" alt="original trombones logo" />
 </div>
<!-- Nav bar -->
 <nav id="nav-bar">
  <ul>
   <li><a class="nav-link" href="#features">Features</a></li>
   <li><a class="nav-link" href="#how-it-works">How It Works</a></li>
   <li><a class="nav-link" href="#pricng">Pricing</a></li>
  </ul>
 </nav>

 </header>


</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I want Feaures, How it works and pricing to all have 33% of ul

Answer (score 1):

the "flex" and justify-content goes in the parent element (ul).

like this:

```css
/** global element styling **/

@import 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700';

body {
  background-color: #eee;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}

.logo {
 flex-basis:40%;
 border: 1px solid red;
}

.logo img {
 width:100%;
 max-width: 300px;
}

header {
 display: flex;
}

header nav {
 border: 1px solid black;
 width: 60%;
 display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-around;
}

header nav ul {
    display: inline-flex;
 justify-content: space-between;
 flex: 1;
}

#nav-bar ul li {
 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
 <title>Product Landing Page</title>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
<div class="page-wrapper">
<!--Header-->
 <header id="header">

<!-- Logo -->  
 <div class="logo">
   <img id="header-img" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/original_trombones.png" alt="original trombones logo" />
 </div>
<!-- Nav bar -->
 <nav id="nav-bar">
  <ul>
   <li><a class="nav-link" href="#features">Features</a></li>
   <li><a class="nav-link" href="#how-it-works">How It Works</a></li>
   <li><a class="nav-link" href="#pricng">Pricing</a></li>
  </ul>
 </nav>

 </header>


</div>
</body>
</html>
```